# Nuclear FISSION origin

Tags: energy, mass, nuclear-physics, weak-interaction, strong-force

Neutrons and protons consist of quarks, and when a neutron and a proton are squeezed tightly enough together, the quarks in each begin to interact and cause them to attract one another. The resulting bound state represents a lower energy configuration that what existed before, which means that when the binding occurs, energy is released, and the bound particles remain stuck together.  If this happens then if a nucleus is bombarded with a neutron , doesn't the neutron bond with the other protons due to the strong force when they come close enough to exchange mesons?

Comment: There are plenty of neutron absorption reactions out there, particularly at low neutron energies. Some of the resulting nuclei are stable as is, some are not. At higher energies the neutron can do more things to the nuclear structure, providing various paths to shedding the extra energy (alpha or gamma emission, fission, protons or deuterons or tritons coming out - lots of possible reactions can be found).

Comment: An excellent answer , no doubt,  but I still didn't understand. :(

Comment: OK, a probably bad analogy - a man and a women are a couple, 'bound' to each other. Another woman interacts with the couple, and becomes 'bound' to the man through interactions. Is the three-body system stable all the time?

Comment: :× a scientific theory ?

Comment: Is psychology or sociology scientific?

Comment: Just asking for a scientific explanation in simple but explanatory terms

Comment: Is there any scientific explanation?

Comment: Well, yes, nuclear physics looks at the energetics of assemblies of neutrons and protons. The point is, you can’t look at the ‘new’ neutron interacting with just one proton - it has to fit in with all the other nuclei. Your way would also say you can keep adding electrons without limit to an atom, since the ‘new’ electron will be attracted to a proton. That ignores everything else, which just isn’t correct.